# Delete an author in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to delete an author from biblatex. The following MWE doesn't do much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=literal]{NameDeleted}

\DeclareFieldFormat{NameDeleted}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}%
    \newunit%
    \printfield{NameDeleted}%
}


% The format of the name to be ignored is stored in \NameToDelete as
% \namepartfamily|\namepartgiven|\namepartprefix|\namepartsuffix
\newcommand{\NameToDelete}{Bertram|Aaron||}
\begin{document}
\cite{bertram,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Instead of getting the standard output, I would like the Bertram reference to be

> Richard Wentworth [Name Deleted]. “Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces”. In: J. Amer. Math. Soc. 9.2 (1996), pp. 529–571.

Maybe it is best to do this with `\DeclareStyleSourcemap`, but from the biblatex documentation maybe it is better to do this with `\DeclareNameInputHandler` (although the documentation for this is pretty thin).

Comment: out of curiosity: what's the reason behind this?

Comment: @naphaneal I manage my CV with biblatex and there are some entrytypes where is makes sense to delete my name.

Comment: Have a look at [`biblatex-publist`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist).

Comment: @moewe thanks. I forgot about that style. It takes a totally different approach and deals with names as they are being formatting. I am making progress with deleting them in the sourcemap, but expansion and protecting spaces is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be at least 4 ways of handling this.

1. The easiest, but least versatile is to edit the bib file directly. The drawbacks of this is if you ever want to do something different, you have to edit the file again. This is the earliest you can make the change
2. The [biblatex-publist](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist) package has this feature. It processes the names at the latest possible time (right before typesetting). The code is relatively long and complex and hard codes the output formatting of the names and only supports family-given and given-family formatting. The code could probably be expanded to handle all the name formats.
3. Use the source map to change the name as it is being read from the bib file into the bbl file by biber:

--

```
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
\maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    % Single author
    \map{
        \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\s and\s}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \NameToDelete, final]
        \step[fieldset = author, null]
        \step[fieldset = usera, fieldvalue = {The Author Was Deleted}]
    }
    % First author
    \map{
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\s and\s}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = {\NameToDelete\ and }, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = {\NameToDelete\ and }, replace = {and }]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{^\s*and\s+(.+)}, replace = \regexp{$1}]
        \step[fieldset = usera, fieldvalue = {The Author Was Deleted}]
    }
    % Middle author
    \map{
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\s and\s}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = { and \NameToDelete\ and}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = { and \NameToDelete\ and}, replace = { and and }]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(.+)\s+ and\s and\s+(.+)}, replace = \regexp{$1 \x20 and\x20 $2}]
        \step[fieldset = usera, fieldvalue = {The Author Was Deleted}]
    }
    % Last author
    \map{
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\s and\s}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = { and \NameToDelete}, final]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = { and \NameToDelete}, replace = { and}]
        \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(.+)\s+ and$}, replace = \regexp{$1}]
        \step[fieldset = usera, fieldvalue = {The Author Was Deleted}]
    }
}
```

}

As biber allows names to be entered as either Doe, John or John Doe, the example needs to be expanded to handle all possible cases. Someone with better regex foo than I could probably make this a lot cleaner. It is also sensitive to the number of spaces in the bib file and the definition of `\NameToDelete`

4. Process the names as they are read from the bbl file into LaTeX with `\DeclareNameInputHandler`. At this point the names have been processed by biber so spurious spaces are taken care of and the ordering of the name parts in the bib file do not matter. To make the matching easier, it is possible to simply match to the name hash created by biber.

--

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}


\newcommand{\HashToDelete}{8a5b475249c01d8aa99f2275128c1037}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\newcounter{myAuthor}
\newtoggle{myNameDeleted}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeleteName}{mm}{% Hash, Authors
    \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{#2}%
    \str_if_in:nnTF{#2}{hash=#1}{%
        \setcounter{myAuthor}{\numexpr\NewCount-1\relax}%
        \edef\NewCount{\themyAuthor}%
        \regex_replace_all:nnN{\cB\{\cB\{hash=#1.*?\cE\}\cE\}\cE\}}{}\l_tmpa_tl%
        \edef\NewValue{\l_tmpa_tl}%
        \global\toggletrue{myNameDeleted}
    }{}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareNameInputHandler{author}{%
    \global\togglefalse{myNameDeleted}
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\DeleteName%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
            \expandafter\HashToDelete\expandafter%
        }\expandafter{%
            \NewValue%
        }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\printnames{author}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
    {}%
    \newunit%
    \iftoggle{myNameDeleted}{%
        \printtext[brackets]{The Author Was Deleted}%
    }{}%
}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bertram,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't allow for changing other fields. The `\toggletrue` part is over written by the time the bibliography is printed.